# Save object as string, while not using serialize

Tags: php, string, object

For error logging I want to save an object as string in my database. I don't want to use serialization because that triggers the `__sleep()`-method. So is there another way to save an object as string without using `serialize()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
$string = print_r($x, true);
```

To save `$string` in the databse you could compress the string:

```
$string = gzcompress($string);
```

To uncompress and print `$string` use:

```
echo '<pre>'.gzuncompress($string).'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo {
  public function __toString() {
    return "Hooray";
  }
}

echo new Foo;
```

Maybe even

```
echo var_export(new Foo, true);
```

Comment: this returns: Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency?

Comment: @arnoudhgz Sorry, but what should this tell me? Obviously you have cyclic dependencies. Depending on which of both you mean by "this" you must resolve them on your own.

Comment: that's true, but I can't use your solution in my case. Thanks for helping anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could to this:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($x);
ob_get_contents();
```

Answer (score 0):

an other solution might be the `json_encode`-function ([docu](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).

EDIT: the nice thing about it is, that you can easily parse it with nearly any programming language if you have to automatically analyse your log files ;-)